# form element index in javascript for use in jquery .change function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get an index of a form element that is passed in to a .change statement.

example HTML form code

```
<tr><td>Question1</td><td><select class=list1 id=l[1] name=l[1]><option value=1>1<option value=2> 2 <option value=3> 3 </select></td><td><select class=hideme name=x[1] id=x[1]></select></td></tr>
<tr><td>Question2</td><td><select class=list1 id=l[1] name=l[2]><option value=1>1<option value=2> 2 <option value=3> 3 </select></td><td><select class=hideme name=x[2] id=x[2]></select></td></tr>
<tr><td>Question3</td><td><select class=list1 id=l[3] name=l[3]><option value=1>1<option value=2> 2 <option value=3> 3 </select></td><td><select class=hideme name=x[3] id=x[3]></select></td></tr>
```

Now the user will select 1, 2 or 3 from the first pulldown. based on that selection the second pulldown will be loaded with content.

example javascipt jquery function

```
$('.list1').change (function ()
 {
  // here is where I need to pick up the index ie: the [1] [2] or [3] as var id
  var selected = $("#l[id] option:selected");
  var pdata = 'subjectareaid='+selected.val();
  $.ajax({
    type   : "POST",
    cache  : false,
    url    : "subcat.php",
    data   : pdata,
    success: function(data) {
     $('#x[id]').html(data);
     $('#x[id]').removeClass('hideme');
    }
   });
 });
```

This will allow me to populate the second pulldown with the options that were returned by the ajax call based on the selection from the first pulldown.

The table has 54 pulldowns that all have to have this action taken against them (this is to populate a mysql table upon form submission) the pulldowns are (l[id]) primary category (x[id]) sub-category. The subcat selection is hidden until after the main cat is picked and then the select statement is populated.

Comment: I suggest you to put quotes around attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the select element changed at the moment with `$(this)` instead of `var selected = $("#l[id] option:selected");`

You can reach the index of the changing select by reaching index of parent `tr` element of that select element by using [closest() selector](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) of jQuery.

Finally the code block you need, should be like that:

```
  var selected = $(this);
  var selectedIndex = selected.closest("tr").index();     
  var pdata = 'subjectareaid='+selected.val()+"&index="+selectedIndex;
```

Comment: went with:  var ssindex = selected.closest("tr").index()+1; as this needed a base 1 index rather than base 0.

Comment: That is true, it depends how you prefer to use. If the answer is helpful for your question, please mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add double qoutes arround your attributes `"`, this is best practice and will prevent errors if you use spaces in your values. Also make sure your html is valid. You didn't close the `<option>` tags with a `</option>`.

You can use a simple regex to get the index of your select element.

```
$('.list1').change (function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var matches = id.match(/^l\[([0-9]{1,})\]/);
    if (matches) {
        var index = matches[1];
    }
});
```